What's causing leaves to die in these trees?
I think these are cypress trees. Evergreens in Virginia.
Problem started a year ago.

See attached photos.
photo 1

Here in my area these kind of trees is used as hedge. There they tend to have green on the outside only, and if you miss cutting one year and cut the next year back to the same size, they are brown inside. Could it be this? That the yellow/brown parts are to old to stay green?
